# jqGrid keep current page on refresh

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to get a jqGrid table to keep its current page on a reload.  I've found some samples, but they don't seem to work for me.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
grid.setGridParam({datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:currentPage}]);
```

It refreshes but always redisplays the first page.

Comment: can you provide the link. I want to see the parameters  and the code where you get the value of currentPage

Comment: I just had currentPage set to a literal value of 2.  Since I couldn't get the paging to work, I never got around to setting that to a real value.

Comment: @Chester:  any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

To retain the page on a redraw simply use this:

```
grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
```

As a matter of interest, you can also get the current page using:

```
var currentPageVar = grid.getGridParam('page');
```

Addition:

'grid' is defined thus:

```
var grid = jQuery("#grid");
```

Which refers to the ID of the grid table in the HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? This code will redraw the grid with the current page still in view...

Comment: The design specs call for the page to go back to the server to obtain updated data and put that data into the grid, but without changing the grid page.

Comment: Did you try : 'grid.setGridParam({datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{current:true}]);' ?

Comment: Yes I did.  It reloads the data from the server, but always goes back to the first page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simply this code:

```
 jQuery("#your_id").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: That code keeps the current page, but doesn't do a refresh.  AFAIK, I have to do the ".setGridParam({datatype:'json'})" to force it to go back to the server for fresh data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
grid.trigger("reloadGrid", {page: currentPage, fromServer: true});
```

or

```js
grid.trigger("reloadGrid", {current: true, fromServer: true});
```

in case of usage [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork. **It's important to use `forceClientSorting: true` together with `loadonce: true`**.

The reason of the problem, which you describe, is the following: jqGrid can display the second page only if it would make **local** paging. If you use only `loadonce: true` then jqGrid display always the first page. More then that, *the server* have to sort the data returned from the server. The option `forceClientSorting: true` inform free jqGrid to do filtering, sorting and paging *locally* after loading the data from the server and **before** displaying the first (or another) page. The option `forceClientSorting: true` allows to load relatively large set of data from foreign source (which data one can't control), filter the data locally (to display only required subset of data), sort the result and to display the page of resulting data.

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for this code

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid("loadData");
```